Struggling with Rust generics
I'm still struggling with Rust generics. The code below simplifies the problem I'm currently facing as much as possible. This code results in a compilation error, and I simply can't understand why it isn't working. The details have been documented within the source code comments. Could you please take a look and offer any advice?
// Assume this trait is NOT object safe, so we cannot use dynamic dispatch 
// like `Box<dyn Callable>` and `&dyn Callable`.
trait Callable {
    fn call(&self);
}

struct Test;

impl Callable for Test {
    fn call(&self) {}
}

fn f<T: Callable>() {
    let callback = |v: T| { v.call(); };
    // The `Test` type has implemented the `Callable` trait. Then why can't 
    // `Test{}` be passed to a variable as `T: Callable`?
    callback(Test{});
}

fn main() {
    f::<Test>();
}


The callback requires T not Test. For f::<Test>() then T happens to be Test. However, for f::<LiterallyAnythingElse>() that could impl Callable then T is not Test

Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do here? The cause of your problem is explained in the answer, and the fix for the code you've shown is to trivially modify the type the closure expects - but I assume your actual issue is different. Give us more info so we can help you.

Generics in Rust are chosen by the caller, and a function must work regardless of the caller’s choice of generic; calling f::<T>() must work for any choice of T: Callable. callback is of type Fn(T) but is being called with parameter Test{}, which is not (necessarily) of type T.
If you want to stick with this design, there isn't really a fix here, since closures can't be generic. You just have to write Test{}.call();. But you could make callback a generic function instead of a closure.
fn callback<T: Callable>(v: T) {
    v.call();
}

fn f() {
    callback(Test{});
}

fn main() {
    f();
}

